# Semidirect product of $G$-posets

Tags: gr.group-theory, posets

Let $P$ be a poset on which a partially ordered group $G$ acts by monotone bijections. I call these guys *$G$-posets*. If I'm not wrong, the semidirect product of two partially ordered groups remains partially ordered. It is then possible to ask:

> 1. If $P$ is a $G$-poset and $Q$ a $H$-poset, is there a way to find a third poset that I call for now $P\rtimes_\phi Q$ which has an action of $G\rtimes_\phi H$ (for a given $\phi : H\to Aut(G)$)?
> 2. Is there a way to promote this construction to a functor
>      $$
>    G\text{-Pos}\times H\text{-Pos} \to (G\rtimes_\phi H)\text{-Pos}
>    $$
> 3. Given a $(G\rtimes_\phi H)$-poset $P$ is there a way to find when there are $P_G, P_H$ such that $P\cong P_G\rtimes_\phi P_H$?

Comment: What's a partially order group? A group with a partial order? left-invariant? bi-invariant? What's the order on the semidirect product?

Comment: $G$ is a group $(G,\cdot)$ and a poset $(G,\le)$, and moreover the group operation is a two-sided congruence: for every $g\le g'$ and $h\in G$ one has $hg\le hg'$ and $gh\le g'h$.

Comment: I lost the page where I did the computation, but (as soon as you assume that $\phi$ is monotone, which I forgot to mention) the order on $G\rtimes H$ is simply the product-order on $G\times H$ (the semidirect product is obviously the product with a different group operation)... am I wrong?

Comment: This seems (at least under some further restrictions) obtainable from a combination of two particular cases of the following: given a small category $C$ and an internal category $F$ in $\mathbf{Cat}^C$, there is an equivalence $\left(\mathbf{Cat}^C\right)^F\simeq\mathbf{Cat}^{F\rtimes C}$.

Comment: What is ${\bf Cat}^C$, where is this result stated and what are the further restrictions?